# Update group & roles to project in python-redmine

Tags: python, json, redmine

I'm trying really hard to find out how to make simple Python script which will change one of my Redmine Projects to **public** and add specified **roles**, **groups**. I manage to change to public, but roles and groups - not so much...

It would be awesome if someone could help me. I've read the documentation of python-redmine: http://python-redmine.readthedocs.org/ but I don't see nothing related to my problem.

Python 2.7.3 @ Debian 7

This is my sample:

```
from redmine import Redmine

redmine = Redmine('http://example.net', key='mykey')
project = redmine.project.get('project-ident-2014')

mygroup = redmine.group.get(4, include='memberships,users')
myrole = redmine.role.get(6)

redmine.project.update(33, is_public=True, group=mygroup, role=myrole)
```

Error output below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redmine/managers.py", line 212, in update
return self.redmine.request('put', url, data=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redmine/__init__.py", line 67, in request
kwargs['data'] = json.dumps(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 200, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 263, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 177, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <redmine.resources.Role #6 "Uczestnik dyżurów"> is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well memberships can be manipulated through http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Memberships but that may not be as easy as doing something through native Redmine objects as I told you on IRC. I don't know python really well, but it seems python-redmine already knows how to do things with the "memberships" resource. You may have to treat the groups addition and the make-the-project-public steps separately though.

Here's a ruby script that might do what you want (put it in the "script" directory)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

#load redmine app
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

#find your project by its identifier
project = Project.find("project-ident-2014")

#define the group you want to add to the project
group = Group.find(4)

#define the role you want to give to this group
role = Role.find(6)

#add a membership with those roles
Member.create!(:principal => group, :project => project, :roles => [role])

#make the project public
project.update_attribute(:is_public, true)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Python-redmine is just wrapper which implements basic API of redmine. So for your need there is no api in redmine: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Projects

API fro Projects supports updating only this values(Redmine v2.5.2):

```
'name',
'description',
'homepage',
'is_public',
'identifier',
'custom_field_values',
'custom_fields',
'tracker_ids',
'issue_custom_field_ids'
'enabled_module_names'
'inherit_members'
```

To solve your issue you can write redmine plugin which will respond on your requests and do all stuff.